# How can I put two div-tags next to each other?

Tags: html

How can I put two div-tags next to each other? I tried this:

```
<div>text 1</div><div>text 2</div>
```

But they appear underneath each other, just as I would have written them in two lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Div's are block level elements, meaning they'll occupy all available space unless told otherwise. In order to display them side-by-side, you'll need to use the CSS property `float`.

**CSS**

```
.float-left{
    float: left;
}
```

than in **HTML** just assign that class name like:

```
<div class="float-left"> 1 </div>
<div class="float-left"> 2 </div>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks @Roko, that phrasing is pretty misleading! I'll edit my original post.

Comment: @AlmostSmart You can always say "thanks" by marking a useful answer as correct. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried this now, but it does not work: `<div float-left{loat: left;}>text 1</div><div float-left{float: left;}>text 2</div>`

Comment: @AlmostSmart please use **stylesheet** don't mess with inline styles (You're even doing it wrong btw, it should be `<div style="float:left;"></div>`) or as I've said `<div class="float-left"></div>` and than put the CSS inside a stylesheet.

Comment: I dont know what stylesheets are, but `<div style="float:left;"></div>` works just fine, so thank you again!

Comment: @AlmostSmart please don't!. Use google and find out how to use CSS styles **properly**.

Comment: I just looked at this CSS a bit and what you can do with that looks pretty neat.
Also I managed to put it in a *.css file. Works now as well.

Answer (score 1):

### use css float:

you need float: left or right with a specified width for the divs to be aligned beside each other.

```html
<div style="float:left; width:50%; background:yellow">text 1</div><div style="float:left; width:50%; background:green">text 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need floats for something this simple. Simply changing the display type to inline will take care of this for you.

See my pen here:
http://codepen.io/KempfCreative/pen/oLNqMZ

```
div { display: inline; }
```

is all you need

Comment: `display: inline;` is the worst option to add to a DIV "block-level" element. Inline would be better used for contextual elements. `display: inline-block;` would be a better suggestion. Or if you really like the `inline` idea than you could simply suggest to use i.e: `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: Agree that making a div 'display: inline' is a terrible semantic decision. However, it is the most reasonable answer to the question without getting embroiled in a larger conversation about proper HTML markup which is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

for a perfect resizing use flexbox
wrap those divs in one parent
with this the inner divs will stretch completely

```
<div id="parent">
<div>text 1</div><div>text 2</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#parent{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
width: 100%;
}
#parent div{
flex-grow:1;
}
```